# In R, getURL() results a page saying too many request. But that page is viewable in Broswer

Tags: html, r

I am trying to get the page from www.dotabuff.com.

```
  library(RCurl)
  url <- "http://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/matchups"
  webpage <- getURL(url,verbose = TRUE)
```

The result is a page from dotabuff complaining too many requests. I was expecting a html page with a table, like the one viewable in a web browser. I have tried http, https, getURLContent, etc.

I think this has something to do with the type of request getURL sent, or maybe something tricky about that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a header to the request...

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "http://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/matchups"
options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = TRUE, useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13"))
webpage <- getURL(url,verbose = TRUE)
*   Trying 23.235.40.64...
* Connected to www.dotabuff.com (23.235.40.64) port 80 (#0)
> GET /heroes/abaddon/matchups HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13
Host: www.dotabuff.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: I assume this is that website's way of trying to avoid being scraped. Try to be respectful and don't hammer them with too many requests.